# Question 10.17 (a) Apostol's Mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This question is from apostol  Mathematical analysis Chapter 10.

> Assume that $f \in \mathbb{R}$ on $[a,b]$ for every $b>a>0$. Define $g$ by the equation $x g(x)=\int_{1}^{x} f(t) dt$ if $x>0$, assume that $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$ exists and $a$ and $b$ are fixed positive integers. Prove that :

$$\int_a^{b} f(x)/x dx=  g(b) -g(a) +\int_{a}^b g(x)/xdx.$$

I tried using  $x g(x)=\int_{1}^{x} f(t) dt$ and trying to work with both LHS and RHS 1 at a time and trying to get other but failed.

I am not getting any other Idea.

So, How should I attempt this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the derivative  with respect to $x$ for
$$x g(x)=\int_{1}^{x} f(t) dt,$$

one gets:
$$ g(x)+xg'(x)= f(x) $$
divide both sides by $x\neq0$:

$$ g(x)/x+g'(x)= f(x)/x $$

Integrating both sides from $a$ to $b$ and using $\int_a^bg'(x)dx=g(b) -g(a)$, completes the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Integrating by parts,
$$\int \frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx=\int (xg(x))'\cdot \frac{1}{x}\,dx=xg(x)\cdot \frac{1}{x}-\int xg(x)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)'\, dx.$$